# Certain browsers stopped working (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Tags: networking, dns, anti-virus

I have Windows 11. Recently Edge, Chrome and Brave all stopped working on my Desktop PC (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET). Firefox and Vivaldi still work. I have tried resetting all the network settings back to the default in Edge. I also disabled all my extensions in Edge. I have rebooted. I have tried different cables. I have run Windows Update. The problematic PC just has Ethernet it does not have Wifi but I plugged the ethernet cable into a USB adapter instead of the network card, no difference. I tried using different DNS. Other PCs do not have an issue. Can only think of a total reinstall next.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was Kaspersky AV. I fixed it like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/antivirus/comments/zremim/im_receiving_err_connection_reset_in_some/?rdt=36505&onetap_auto=true&one_tap=true

> 1. Disable Self-Defense via Settings -> General.
> 2. Exit Kaspersky product, on the Windows Taskbar or hidden icons, rightclick the Kaspersky icon, select Exit.
> 3. Go to folder C:\ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab\AVP21.3, rename the folder Report to Report1.
> 4. Shutdown machine using Shutdown, not Restart, power on the machine by pressing the power button, login. Start KIS.
> 5. Enable Self-Defense.
> 6. Re-check problem

Comment: Added quotes as required when citing.